# layout inflator for listview in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have complete column values from the database in arraylist. But i want to display only message and date columns in the listview.
my code:

```
    public class DisplayAllNotification extends Activity

    {
    ListView lv;
    Context context;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notif);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        SqlitenotifDb db = new SqlitenotifDb(getApplicationContext(),
                "notifManager", null, 1);

        ArrayList<NotificationData> lstString = new ArrayList<NotificationData>();
        lstString = db.getNotifications();// catch NotificationData obj


        NotificationAdapter notificationAdapter = new NotificationAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lstString);
        lv.setAdapter(notificationAdapter);


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                    long id) {

                    //on click want to display 2 columns in listview
                        }
        });

    }

NotificationAdapter.java

    public class NotificationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NotificationData>{

    private Context context;
    private int resource;
    private ArrayList<NotificationData> objects;

    public NotificationAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            ArrayList<NotificationData> objects) 
    {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.resource = resource;
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
    }   
}
```

Comment: You must share your NotificationAdapter to get answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a lot on using a listView with a custom adapter. I suggest you to read more about custom adapters and listView. Anyway, here is a complete code to solve your problem:

Define a layout under `res/layout` and name it `my_list_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You haven't implemented your custom adapter. You can use below code for your adapter:

```
public class NotificationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NotificationData> {

    private Context context;
    private int resource;
    private ArrayList<NotificationData> objects;

    public NotificationAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<NotificationData> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.resource = resource;
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            View listRow = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resource, null);
            convertView = listRow;
        }

        TextView textView1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        NotificationData notificationData = getItem(position);

        textView1.setText(notificationData.getMessage());
        textView2.setText(notificationData.getDate());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public NotificationData getItem(int position) {
        if (this.objects != null) {
            return this.objects.get(position);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (this.objects != null) {
            return this.objects.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally `onCreate` method of your activity change this code;

```
NotificationAdapter notificationAdapter = new NotificationAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lstString);
```

with

```
NotificationAdapter notificationAdapter = new NotificationAdapter(this,
            R.layout.my_list_item, lstString);
```

Comment: I want to retrieve column values from the arraylist for further code. can you guide me in this that how to retrieve item field's values.

Comment: You can retrieve any value from your NotificationData object. And you can change your row my_list_item.xml and your adapter to show different values.

Answer (score 0):

Three solutions, choose one.

1- Assuming NotificatioData class hold all columms.
Define another class with only the colums that you want display.
Fill it from NotificationData
Pass that array to Adapter

2 - From `db.getNotifications()` return a array with only the colums that you want display.

3 - Since the data source is a database use a CursorAdapter. In the `bindView` method bind only the colums you want to the list views items.